# How to return an object from controller to ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am creating dashboard in ROR.  I have a combobox which onchange sends the ajax get to the dashboard to get the data accordingly. Based on my value selected i will get the data and i will render the values in highcharts accordingly.

```
hbar.html.erb

    <select  name="hBarParam" id="hBarParam" class="hBarParam">
        <option value="Nothing"></option>
        <option value="Today" class="selected">Today</option>
        <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
        <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
     </select>

    <div id="postsHBar" style="width:100%; height:500px" class="postsHBar"></div>
    $(".hBarParam").change(function(){

          var str = $( "#hBarParam option:selected" ).text();

            $.get("/dashboard/hbar?hBarParam="+str,function( data){

              alert(<%= @postsHBarClean.map{|p|p[1] } %>)

            }).done(function() {
              alert(<%= @postsHBarClean.map{|p|p[1] } %>)
              //render new highcharts with different like postsHBarClean,        postsHBarSalvage,etc

  $( function () {
    new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
              type: 'bar',
              renderTo: 'postsHBar',
              backgroundColor:null

          },
          title: {
              text:...
          },
          xAxis: {
              categories: <%= raw @postsHBar.map{|p| p.make_vehicle}.map(&:to_s) %>,

          },
          yAxis: {
              min: 0,
              title: {
                  text: 'Count (Thousands)',
                  align: 'high'
              }...
          legend: {
              layout: 'vertical',
              align: 'right',
              verticalAlign: 'top',
              x: -40,
             ....
          },
          credits: {
              enabled: false
          },
         series: [{
          name: "Clean",
          data: <%= @postsHBarClean.map{|p|p[1] } %>

      },
      {
          name: "Salvage",
          data: <%= @postsHBarSalvage.map{|p|p[1] } %>

      }.....]
      });
  });    
            });
          });
```

Controller code

```
    class DashboardController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :html, :js, :json
      # GET /dashboard/hbar
      def hbar
        puts params["hBarParam"]
        if params["hBarParam"] == "Today"
             postsHBarParam = "created_day = 26"

        elsif params["hBarParam"] == "Monthly"
          postsHBarParam = "created_month = 'April'"
        else
         postsHBarParam = "created_day between 22 and 27"
        end
        puts postsHBarParam
     #   postsHBarParam = "created_day = 26"


        @postsHBarClean = Post.where(postsHBarParam + " and title_status like ? and make_vehicle is not null", "clean").group(:make_vehicle).count.to_a
        @postsHBarSalvage = Post.where(postsHBarParam +" and title_status like ? and make_vehicle is not null", "salvage").group(:make_vehicle).count.to_a
        @postsHBarPartsOnly = Post.where(postsHBarParam +" and title_status like ? and make_vehicle is not null", "parts only").group(:make_vehicle).count.to_a
        @postsHBarRebuilt = Post.where(postsHBarParam +" and title_status like ? and make_vehicle is not null", "rebuilt").group(:make_vehicle).count.to_a
        @postsHBarLien = Post.where(postsHBarParam +" and title_status like ? and make_vehicle is not null", "lien").group(:make_vehicle).count.to_a
        @postsHBar = Post.select(:make_vehicle).where(postsHBarParam +" and title_status is not null and make_vehicle is not null" ).uniq
        puts @postsHBarClean

    respond_to do |format|
     format.js
         format.html
       end
end
```

The problem is that the chart renders.. but with default values (i.e else part in controller) so whenever i change the select option .. 'puts string' works but charts takes the same values i.e those that were during the page load.
There is no syntax error or brackets missing :P

I am badly stuck at the issue and dont know how to resolve it. :(

Comment: You need to use `hbar.js.erb` in order to respond to the `hbar` action as `JS` (not as `HTML`)

Comment: create hbar.js.erb as suggested and write code to render chart with new values in that js.erb file

Comment: you should put all code of hbar.html.erb in a partial _hbar.html.erb render the same partial from controller

Comment: You've got two sensible options:  A) use rails to generate a big chunk of html using the data and a partial, and send this html back to the client, which replaces a part of the page.  B) Send the data back as JSON and let the javascript in the client decide what to do with it.  A is generally preferable if you're updating part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a AJAX call you should answer as JS.

If I understood right, your controller should send something back to the AJAX call. So your controller should render a JSON. Something like:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render: postsHBarClean.to_json }
    format.html
  end
end
```

And your JavaScript you should handle with the JSON response.

Take time to read the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html
And watch this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised

Comment: and how to i render multiple jsons. I am new to rails and ajax.

Comment: @NiveditaSancheti what do you mean for multiple jsons?